# php сравнение и поиск одинаковых имен

Tags: php

Если в сравнении одно слово, то находит и нормально выводятся данные, а если несколько слов и через пробел, но совпадают слова не хочет выводить. Как победить такое

```
$name_r = str_replace($s_name_r,$replace_name,$name); // здесь передается такое значение -- Яблоки "Груши тыква"  --- с пробелом
$tr = 'Яблоки "'.$namef.'"'; // здесь выводится другие данные для сравнения  

foreach(explode(' ', $tr) as $word) {
    if(stripos($name_r, $word) !== false) {
        echo "Found";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name_r = 'Яблоки "Груши тыква"';
$trs = ['Яблоки "Груши тыква"', 'Яблоки "Груши', '"Груши тыква"', 'Яблоки тыква"'];

foreach ($trs as $tr) {
    foreach(explode(' ', $tr) as $word) {
        if(stripos($name_r, $word) !== false) {
            echo "Found";
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Вывод

```
FoundFoundFoundFound
```

Как мы можем видеть, 4 разные шаблона поиска с пробелом показали положительный результат. Что у вас не ищет, не понятно.

Comment: Я так подозреваю лишние невидимые символы какие либо еще передаются( возможно в словах дополнительные пробелы передаются